# Best way to color a Box2d body using LibGDX

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I just started playing with a very simple game and I do not want to create sprites images for every single body,I just need to colour them with different colours.

As per this thread, ShapeRendere seems to be not a very good idea and it is more for development: [When to use ShapeRenderer, Mesh + SpriteBatch, Box2D and Scene2D in Libgdx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991953/when-to-use-shaperenderer-mesh-spritebatch-box2d-and-scene2d-in-libgdx)

Also, tint can be only be used on textures which require images as well:
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Spritebatch,-textureregions,-and-sprite

This is one the bodies I am trying to colour:

```
          //Dynamic Body  
      bodyDef = new BodyDef(); 
      //bodyDef.gravityScale
      bodyDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;  
      bodyDef.position.set(camera.viewportWidth / 2, camera.viewportHeight / 2);  
      body = world.createBody(bodyDef);  
      CircleShape dynamicCircle = new CircleShape();  
      dynamicCircle.setRadius(10f);  
      FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();  
      fixtureDef.shape = dynamicCircle;  
      fixtureDef.density = 2.5f;  
      fixtureDef.friction = 0.25f;  
      fixtureDef.restitution = 0.75f;  
      body.createFixture(fixtureDef);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can use the code in ShapeRenderer to figure out how it draws the shapes, and then streamline it for your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest not using Sprites directy, but instead turn to scene2d and its Actors. The libgdx wiki already perfectly describes how to do this then.

You would create a class that extends Actor (or Group) and that renders the texture you want.

When creating your box2d bodies, you would set the bodies' user data to the actor via `setUserData(actor);`

Now after simulating the box2d world with step(), you just need to iterate over the bodies in the world, access the actor through `getUserData()` and update the actor's position and rotatin to the current values of the body. The wiki already contains the complete loop needed for this...

Hope it helps... :)